# How to create a Controller to render a custom Error Template in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, custom-error-pages

I'm using Spring Boot and FreeMarker.

To render the header I need to put a dynamically created object in the model. Same to render the footer. I have a page.ftl that every other template includes so that every page have a header and a footer.

I want to render an 404 page which also shows this header and footer, so ideally the view of this page should be a free marker template.

I notice that if I have an error.ftl, Spring Boot would use it in case of an error, but where can I put logic that adds the header and footer so that my error page looks nice?

Answer (score 2):

The answer was to create a @ControllerAdvice

Inside there is one method annotated with @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) and with @ExceptionHandler for the project's own PageNotFoundException. That method returns a ModelAndView object where I can put the name of whatever view I want to render (doesn't matter if it's FreeMarker or not). Inside the method I construct the header and footer.

The same can be done for a 500 page.